# Angular JS + Cross Domain + Web API

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, cors

I am planning to use Angular JS + Web API together for my application.

Technologies : VS 2013, .NET 4.0, MS Server 2003.

I have my Web API & Angular JS Client on two different domains [Mandatory]. I tried achieving what i need using .NET 4.5/4.5.1 with CORS in Web API, but because MS Server 2003 does not support installation > .NET 4.0 have to give up the thought. So the solution might not be fully viable for my case.

Can someone suggest how to achieve this with the above mentioned restrictions in mind?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can make a request to the servers hosting you app, and make cross server requests then.

Comment: Look at jsonp and jsonp media type formatter, if it helps http://www.nuget.org/packages/WebApiContrib.Formatting.Jsonp/

Comment: Thank you for your response. I ended up using .NEt 4.5/4.5.1 instead of 4.0 & VS 2013 to create my Web API with cors support. However i am getting this error "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:port/api/controllerget. Invalid HTTP status code 405" My client method looks like below:

$http({method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:port/api/contget'
            }).success(function (data, status) {
            }).error(function (data, status) {
            });
        };

What am i missing?

Comment: @Immortal that sounds like your Web API is returning a code that doesn't exist, namely 405. Thus, your probelm isn't in the `$http()` call from angularjs, but your implementation of the endpoint in .NET on the API side.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this (to 'avoid' CORS that is) is to implement a solution that has a sever-side component as well as the client-side (angular). AngularJS would call the server-side (same web site, really, but a different path) that would then call the server. Thus, a *client* is not calling the web API directly, but the *server* is.

There's security concerns to be aware of, of course, but the general idea still applies: make your API calls from the server instead of client, and have the client call the server.